# Shared class field in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, static-methods

I have a class, `MyClass`, declared as public, with a `Shared` method `test()`:

```
Public Class MyClass
  Public Shared Function test()
    Return "sdfg"
  End Function

  ' snip other non-shared methods
End Class
```

This `Class` is located in the `App_Code` directory of the website, and appears to be visible, as I can instantiate an instance of the Class from any of the sites scripts.

My issue relates specifically to accessing the `Shared` method `test()`. Trying to get this working, I have the following code in `Page_Load()` of one of the scripts:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)
  Response.Write MyClass.test()

  Dim myClassVar As MyClass = new MyClass()
  myClassVar.nonSharedMethod()
End Sub
```

If I comment out `Response.Write MyClass.test()`, everything works fine and I can use the `Class` - however, trying to access the `Shared` method, I get the following error:

```
Local variable 'myClass' cannot be referred to before it is declared
```

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that in obfuscating this code for posting purposes, you've masked the fact that you have a variable with the name `MyClass` also declared in your page load (that *is* what the error is basically saying).

Comment: I realise that this example is probably an abstraction, but does this still happen if you change the class name to `AClass` instead of `MyClass`? `MyClass` is a keyword in VB.Net, this could be causing your problme.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes, that is exactly what was happening... I had a variable of type MyClass called myClass, and VB is apparently treating myCLass == MyClass in terms of the variable name. Interesting, thanks for the help. Can you post this as a solution so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that in obfuscating this code for posting purposes, you've masked the fact that you have a variable with the name `MyClass` also declared in your page load (that is what the error is basically saying).

Visual Basic is a case insensitive language. Declaring your variable as `myClass` is the same as declaring it as `MYCLASS` or `myclass`, and the line `MyClass.test()` will be resolving the name `MyClass` to that variable - which as the error indicates, hasn't been declared yet.