# MyClass equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830825/shared-class-field-in-visual-basic), commenter @Jon Egerton mentioned that `MyClass` was a keyword in `VB.Net`. Having never used it, I went and found the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0.aspx) on it:

> The MyClass keyword behaves like an object variable referring to the current instance of a class as originally implemented. MyClass is similar to Me, but all method calls on it are treated as if the method were NotOverridable.

I can see how that could kind of be useful, in some specific scenarios. What I can't think of is, how would you obtain the same behaviour in C# - that is, to ensure that a call to a virtual method `myMethod` is actually invoked against `myMethod` in the current class, and not a derived `myMethod` (a.k.a in the IL, invoking `call` rather than `callvirt`)?

I might just be having a complete mental blank moment though.

Comment: Of course, you could do this with reflection and `DynamicMethod` and custom IL-generation (using `call` rather than `callvirt` as you suggest), but you'd end up with a lot of ugly code for something that's probably a bad idea in the first place. If you really need this behaviour for some reason then Heinzi's workaround is the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[According to Jon Skeet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88476.aspx), there is no such equivalent:

> No, C# doesn't have an equivalent of VB.NET's MyClass keyword. If you want to guarantee not to call an overridden version of a method, you need to make it non-virtual in the first place.

An obvious workaround would be this:

```
public virtual void MyMethod()
{
    MyLocalMethod();
}

private void MyLocalMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Then you could call `MyLocalMethod()` when a VB user would write `MyClass.MyMethod()`.

Comment: That seems fine if you're implementing a base class, not so good if you're inheriting and inherited from.

Comment: @Damien: True. Fortunately, it's not hard to work around this limitation (see my edit).

Answer (score 3):

There is no C# equivalent of the MyClass keyword in VB.Net. To guarantee that an overridden version of a method will not be called, simply make it non-virtual.

Comment: And if you want to allow it to be overridden? Or are you saying that this is impossible?

Comment: @George Duckett as far as i can think of yes its impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answers saying it doesn't exist, so you have to make it non-virtual.

Here's a [smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) (read: don't do this!) work-around. But seriously, re-think your design.

Basically move any method that must have the base one called into 'super'-base class, which sits above your existing base class. In your existing class call base.Method() to always call the non-overridden one.

```
void Main()
{
    DerivedClass Instance = new DerivedClass();

    Instance.MethodCaller();
}


class InternalBaseClass
{
    public InternalBaseClass()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BASE METHOD");
    }
}

class BaseClass : InternalBaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {

    }

    public void MethodCaller()
    {
        base.Method();
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {

    }

    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DERIVED METHOD");
    }
}
```