# Explicit use of base method without using keyword new in child method

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Due to the **polymorphism** property of the classes, below example will print `AB` twice, which is expected.

In my case, I really want it to print `A` then `AB`.

I decided to change the `Get()` method in `B` from `overrides` to `new`. 
This solves my problem, but they informed me of bad practise, so I'm looking for an alternative...

The one thing that comes to mind is to `instantiate a new A in B.Do()`, which I think is also bad practise...

```
//ORIGINAL
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.Do();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void Do()
    {
        var get = Get();
        Console.WriteLine(get);
    }

    public virtual string Get()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        base.Do();

        var get = Get();
        Console.WriteLine(get);
    }

    public override string Get()
    {
        return base.Get() + "B";
    }
}

//UPDATED, USING NEW
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.Do();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void Do()
    {
        var get = Get();
        Console.WriteLine(get);
    }

    public virtual string Get()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        base.Do();

        var get = Get();
        Console.WriteLine(get);
    }

    public new string Get()
    {
        return base.Get() + "B";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but is a reference to the feature I think you're looking for: [MyClass equivalent in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6831379/15498)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That might be the solution to my problem as well. Thanks for that, I'll read into it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the base version of `Do` in `B.Do`, you can change the implementation as follows:

```
public class B : A
{
  public override void Do()
  {
    // Call the base version of Get explicitly
    var getBase = base.Get();
    Console.WriteLine(getBase);
    // Call the current implementation of Get
    var get = Get();
    Console.WriteLine(get);
  }

  public override string Get()
  {
    return "B";
  }
}
```

This will technically solve your problem, but is not a really clean solution from an OOP point of view. I suggest to think a bit about whether you need to be able to override `Get` independently. Maybe changing the signatures of your methods so that `Get` always returns a list of strings that should be printed is also a good solution (I've renamed `Get` to `GetLines` to reflect the changed purpose of the method):

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Do()
    {
        var lines = GetLines();
        foreach(var line in lines)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetLines()
    {
        return new string[] { "A" };
    }
}

public class B : A
{

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetLines()
    {
        var lst = new List<string>(base.GetLines());
        lst.Add("B");
        return lst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.Do();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Get());
    }

    public virtual string Get()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(base.Get());
        base.Do();
    }

    public override string Get()
    {
        return base.Get() + "B";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what you're doing is an implicit new on B.Get(). 
Visual Studio even marks this with a squiggly line and tells me I need to implement new.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I missed that part. Sorry :)
I have also updated my question slightly, because B.Get() also calls base.Get(), therefor I cannot use your solution.